# Implementing Inner Join using Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am on the process of learning apache beam framework. I have implemented an Inner join, by looking at the example described in this link. But I am unable to understand it's working completely. K

```
    // Read Cutomer Order File
    PCollection<String> pCollection1 = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(
            "src/main/resources/Join/InnerJoin/CustomerOrder.csv"));

    //Read Customer File
    PCollection<String> pCollection2 = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read()
            .from("src/main/resources/Join/InnerJoin/Customer.csv"));

    //Parse customerOrder data in form of PCollection KeyValue Pair 
    PCollection<KV<String, String>> customerOrderCollection = pCollection1
            .apply(ParDo.of(new CustomerOrderParsing()));

    //Parse Customer data in form of PCollection KeyValue Pair
    PCollection<KV<String, String>> customerCollection = pCollection2.apply(ParDo.of(new CustomerParsing()));

    // Create TupleTag Object
    TupleTag<String> customerOrderrTuple = new TupleTag<String>();
    TupleTag<String> customerTuple = new TupleTag<String>();
```

**unable to understand why we are doing this. On referring to the documentation, I could get that we are aggregating all the elements based on the key value. But why are we doing this?**

```
    PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> result = KeyedPCollectionTuple
            .of(customerOrderrTuple, customerOrderCollection).and(customerTuple, customerCollection)
            .apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());
```

**I don't know what's happening here**

```
    PCollection<String> output = result.apply(ParDo.of(
            new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
                    String strKey = context.element().getKey();
                    CoGbkResult valueObject = context.element().getValue();
                    Iterable<String> customerOrderTable = valueObject.getAll(customerOrderrTuple);
                    Iterable<String> customerTable = valueObject.getAll(customerTuple);
                    
                    for (String order:customerOrderTable) {
                        for (String user:customerTable) {
                            context.output(strKey+","+order+","+user);
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }

    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> result = KeyedPCollectionTuple
            .of(customerOrderrTuple, customerOrderCollection).and(customerTuple, customerCollection)
            .apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());
```

This is actually where your join is happening and it returns a `PCollection` of key-values, where a `key` is a joined key and a `value` contains the all values for this key. So, then you need to iterate over the values of all joined collections for the same key to join them in a way that you need - that is why there is another `DoFn` downstream that performs this in a user specific way.

I agree that this quite verbose and potential error-prone API (since it's quite low-level), so did you consider do you use [Schema-aware](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#using-schemas) `PCollection`s? With this API joins and all other relational operations are much easier to do.

For example, `Inner` join may look like this (much simpler) and it already supports different types of joins:

```
PCollection<Transaction> transactions = readTransactions();
PCollection<Review> reviews = readReviews();
PCollection<Row> joined = transactions.apply(
    Join.innerJoin(reviews).using("userId", "productId"));
```